# VirtualBox failing with error

Tags: virtualbox, lubuntu

I'm trying to install an image of lubuntu (i386) using the ISO: lubuntu-16.04.4-desktop-i386.iso and am getting the following error.

The specific machine does not support VT-X.

I have set 3 GB for the RAM, and one CPU for the core.

[image]

Not sure what I should copy/paste from the logs yet?

Note: This is not related to boot2docker but on how to install a 32 bit linux on a host without vt-x.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to avoid "Guru Meditation" when doing docker pull?](https://superuser.com/questions/974462/is-there-a-way-to-avoid-guru-meditation-when-doing-docker-pull)

Comment: Before I submit an answer to this question, I need to know what runtime error you received, which is contained within vbox.log, at the location specified in the dialog.  It would also help if you provided the image referenced in the dialog also.  You should also indicate what version of Windows you are running on, and specifications on the hardware itself, would help determine the reason you received the runtime error you did.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up working around this by using a simpler and older ISO image, specifically:

ubuntu-14.04.5-server-i386.iso

Accessed list of old repositories using: http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/

Answer (score 0):

When VirtualBox complains about VT-X, at first place, you should check whether your host computer supports virtualisation or not. To enable VTx on your machine, please refer to the [Enabling VTx on BIOS/UEFI](https://www.howtogeek.com/213795/how-to-enable-intel-vt-x-in-your-computers-bios-or-uefi-firmware/) link.

Also, you can enable or disable vt-x for your virtual machine, in order to do that please refer to your virtual machine's configuration `Settings->System->Enable VT-x/AMD-V`.
[Enabing VT-x on VirtualBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y28zk.png)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I had mentioned however `The specific machine does not support VT-X.`

Comment: In the sake of completeness, I added the first part solution. However, please follow `https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/running-virtual-machines-with-and-without-virtualization-hardware-support/` to solve your problem, just be informed VT-x is required when you look at full performance and realistic experience. Moreover, when your computer does not support virtualisation features, please be aware you can run 32-bit guest on a 32-bit host and 64-bit guest on a 64-bit host machine.

Comment: This particular message has nothing to do with VT-X being enabled or disabled.  This is a generic message, that indicates there is a host memory issue, in other words, the guest operating system running within the VM encountered a critical failure due to system resources not being available within the host operating system